# Getting kernel config from defconfig

Tags: linux-kernel, kbuild

The title says it all: I need the `.config` file that was used for compiling a kernel, but all I have is the defconfig file. I've seen instructions on how to produce the latter from the former, but not the other way around. Is it possible?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system

Comment: `make ARCH=<needed_arch> whatever_defconfig`. Be sure that you have proper kernel sources. *whatever_defconfig* should be located under *arch/<needed_arch>/configs/whatever_defconfig*. (There are some exceptions, for example, x86_64 defconfigs are in *arch/x86/configs* folder)

Comment: @0andriy: Wouldn't that command simply build the kernel? That's not really what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

If you know the base config against which your defconfig file was generated, you can merge against it. Kernel version doesn't have to be exactly the same - new options will stay on default.

Assuming the base which your `defconfig` file was generated against was x86_64_defconfig (most likely) and you just have copied it into the linux source tree:

```
$ make mrproper
$ scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh defconfig
```

If there are no errors, the .config file is now ready and you can run `make` to build the kernel.

For further help run `$ scripts/kconfig/merge_config.sh -h` or peek into the script.

Answer (score -2):

You can't.

defconfig files are basic and minimalist config for one target architecture, and are just a starting point used to define a real .config.

You can instead retrieve .config used by other ways : [look here on super-user](https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system)

Comment: LOL, WHAT?! Have you ever build kernel yourself?

Comment: @0andriy, yes I've built lot of kernels, have you understand the question ? Jon don't want to build a kernel from defconfig, he wants to retrieve the .config used to build current running kernel from defconfig. That's not possible ....

Comment: Yes, I do, and could hardly imagine the case where you have binary only kernel with manually altered configuration without that configuration provided. Perhaps some paranoid gentoo server node?

Comment: I would upvote the answer in case you elaborate in which cases one can recover, and in which can't.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer on Superuser for alternative methods of getting the .config file does not help me, since the kernel does not export a `/proc/config.gz` nor there is a config file on `/boot`.